# Tooltip with values while using SpiderWebPlot

Tags: java, plot, tooltip, jfreechart

I'm using SpiderWebPlot from JFreeChart in order to generate a chart. But what I want to have, is tooltips with values. I've found that I should set StandardCategoryTooltipGenerator to the plot, but that doesn't seem to be the point. Here is my sample code:

```
private JFreeChart prepareChart() {
    Random rnd = new java.util.Random();
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    String rowKey = "Osobnik";
    dataSet.addValue(rnd.nextInt(20), rowKey, "BLUFF");
    dataSet.addValue(rnd.nextInt(20), rowKey, "CALL");
    dataSet.addValue(rnd.nextInt(20), rowKey, "CHECK");
    dataSet.addValue(rnd.nextInt(20), rowKey, "FOLD");
    dataSet.addValue(rnd.nextInt(20), rowKey, "RAISE");

    SpiderWebPlot plot = new SpiderWebPlot(dataSet);
    // CategoryToolTipGenerator generator = new
    // StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator();
    // generator.generateToolTip(dataSet, 0, 1);
    plot.setToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());
    plot.setStartAngle(54D);
    plot.setInteriorGap(0.40000000000000002D);
    plot.setToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());
    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(plot);

    return chart;
}
```

Here is the example of what I'm trying to accomplish.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Edited. I've replaced the behaviour pattern get's with rnd.nextInt();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ChartPanel` "registers with the chart to receive notification of changes to any component of the chart." I suspect you have neglected to construct a `ChartPanel`; given a `static` version of `prepareChart()`, the following `main()` works for me. See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Spider Web Plot");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.add(new ChartPanel(prepareChart()));
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Addendum: Based on the posted screenshots, you'll need a custom `CategoryItemLabelGenerator`, which can be set using `setLabelGenerator()`. It will be called from `drawLabel()`, shown [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/plot/SpiderWebPlot.html#line.1421). For example,

```
plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator() {

    @Override
    public String generateColumnLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int col) {
        return dataset.getColumnKey(col) + " " + dataset.getValue(0, col);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've added example to the question.