# JFreeChart:DefaultCategoryDataset addValue adding only upto 3 decimal point

Tags: java, jfreechart

Description :
I am fetching the data from the database, doing certain calculation to get percentage and then adding the percentage to addValue method .
The calculated percentage is for example double percentage =0.068172;

now below is the code to set the above percentage;

```
datasetAnnual.addValue(percentage, TTNIConstants.PERNCENTAGE,
                        String.valueOf(year_2));
getAnnualChart(datasetAnnual);
```

Problem is : the above percnetage value is returning upto 3 decimal digit . that is in this case  the data is 0.068.  But I need it upto 4 decimal digit , i.e. in this case I am expecting 0.0681; 
The graph is displaying  0.068 but I want it to be 0.0681.

Does the addValue() method take only upto 3 decimal ? or  am I supposed to do write some extra code ?

Your help would be immensely appreciated .

This is how I am setting dataset and creating the graph

```
public JFreeChart getAnnualChart(DefaultCategoryDataset datasetAnnual){
        JFreeChart annualChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
                "   Title-1", "Title-2", "Title-3",
                datasetAnnual, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, 
                                                            // false)
                false, 
                false 
                );

        System.out.println(datasetAnnual.getValue(0, 0));


        CategoryAxis domainAxis1 = plot1.getDomainAxis();
        domainAxis1.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));


        plot1.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);
        plot1.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);

        plot1.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.RED);
        plot1.setRangeGridlinesVisible(true);

        plot1.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(204, 255, 153));
        plot1.setOutlineVisible(true);

        plot1.setOutlinePaint(Color.magenta);

        // ValueAxis rangeAxis1 = plot1.getRangeAxis();
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot1.getRangeAxis();

        //rangeAxis1.setUpperMargin(0.15);

        rangeAxis.setLowerMargin(0.15);

        rangeAxis.setLowerBound(0);

        rangeAxis.setUpperBound(1.095);
        rangeAxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        rangeAxis.setLabelFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        rangeAxis.setAutoRangeMinimumSize(4);
        rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.1, new DecimalFormat("##,##,##0%")));
        annualChart.getLegend().setPosition(RectangleEdge.RIGHT);
        LineAndShapeRenderer renderer1 = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
        renderer1.setBaseOutlinePaint(Color.ORANGE);
        renderer1.setDrawOutlines(true);

        renderer1.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
        renderer1.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
        /*renderer1.setItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{2}"
                , NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()));*/
        renderer1.setBaseItemLabelFont(new Font("bold", Font.CENTER_BASELINE,
                12));
        renderer1.setBaseItemLabelPaint(Color.BLUE);
        renderer1.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(
                ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.BOTTOM_CENTER));
        plot1.setRenderer(renderer1);

        return annualChart;

     }
```

Comment: ANd also after doing lot of research it seems the below code should clinch the deal , but it is not doing any effect:rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.1, new DecimalFormat("##,##,##0%")));

Comment: Use [`setNumberFormatOverride()`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20setNumberFormatOverride).

Comment: Thank you for the the info , I tried w this , this is the below code I wrote ,rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(new DecimalFormat(pattern)); but this is changing the y-axxis value not the data I am trying to see on the graph

Comment: _…the data I am trying to see on the graph_. DYM in an item label?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, Yes Yes that is correct , the value which I am showing on the graph is item level , to be more specific on the the range of the y axis and x aixis . my Y axis is 0%,10%,20%,30%,40,....100% and x axis is year 2012,2013, 2014 . and the data in this is case 0.068  at 10% for year 2013 on the graph.

Comment: Override `generateColumnLabel()`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14128200/230513).