# Display values in JFreeChart spider chart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

The spider web plot of [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/index.html) does not display values close to the marked points, as default:

[image: SpiderWebPlot example]

what must be done to display the numbers?

That's what I have now, in a method returning `StreamedContent` (for PrimeFaces' `p:graphicImage`:

```
CategoryDataset categorydataset = createCategoryDataset(displayBy, configuration, null);
SpiderWebPlot plot = new SpiderWebPlot(categorydataset);
plot.setInteriorGap(0.40);
plot.setNoDataMessage("No data available");
plot.setStartAngle(0);
plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{2}", NumberFormat.getInstance()));
plot.setWebFilled(true);

JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(title, TextTitle.DEFAULT_FONT, plot, true);

File chartFile = new File(String.valueOf(new Random().nextLong()));
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(chartFile, chart, 375, 300);
return new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(chartFile), "image/png");
```

EDIT: After @trashgod's suggestion, some values appeared but no in the expected place. I want the `columnKey` values, not the `rowKey' values ([addValue method in DefaultCategoryDataset class](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html#addValue-java.lang.Number-java.lang.Comparable-java.lang.Comparable-)):

[image: dataset.getColumnKey(col) + " TESTE " + dataset.getValue(0, col)]

Comment: Use a `CategoryItemLabelGenerator `, as shown in this [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14122929/230513).

Comment: Did that. Now I created the dataset in that method, it has values because I debugged it right now. Nothing appears. `plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator() { @Override public String generateColumnLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int col) { return dataset.getColumnKey(col) + " TESTE " + dataset.getValue(0, col); } });`

Comment: Edited, see the changes made. Some values appeared but no in the expected place. I need them next to the "points".

Comment: I don't understand; how are the labels not next to the points?

Comment: See the edition I made. Last pic.

Comment: How could they be closer to the points?

Comment: They're linked to the 8 outer categories, but what matters are the 3 others (there are 3 colors we can see if we watch closely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What must be done to display the numbers?*

You can label points on the plot using a [`CategoryItemLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/CategoryDataset.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14128200/230513).

*What matters are the three other [points].*

It looks like you might be able to add a second series, one with a second `rowKey`, in order to get  labels associated with those points.